# Enforce a client hardware address via DHCPv4

Tags: dhcp, network-protocols

Is there a DHCPv4 option that allows a client to tell the server never or at least for some time to deny any other client hardware address than its own?

I'm looking for a way to deny any other host to get the management address the ISP assigns via DHCPv4. Only a certain router is supposed to request that management address. Any other host must not be able to steal the address by sending discovers and requests.

Why can't I prevent this? Because router and modem aren't locked away and therefore I can't stop people in the office from accidentally doing that.

Yes, I'm aware of MAC address spoofing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DHCP server will enforce that it doesn't hand out the same IP address to multiple clients and as long as your router keeps refreshing its DHCP lease and doesn't release the address then another client should not be able to request it.

A client option doesn't make sense as that would be a way to DoS a DHCP server and tie up all of its available leases for an extended period of time.

Comment: You're right. There was a flaw in my reasoning.